# Trying to set squid proxy password on ec2 instance

Tags: 14.04, proxy, squid

I'm trying to set up basic auth on squid proxy on an ubuntu 14.4 EC2 instance. I'm following http://soad1982.blogspot.com/2013/05/squid-proxy-on-aws.html.

Following the article I tried to set a password for a user like so:

What am I doing wrong?

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-36-156:~$ which htpasswd
ubuntu@ip-172-31-36-156:~$ sudo sh -c 'echo "$PATH"'
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

edit:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-36-156:~$ sudo find / -name basic_ncsa_auth
ubuntu@ip-172-31-36-156:~$

ubuntu@ip-172-31-36-156:~$ sudo htpasswd /etc/squid3/passwd soad
sudo: htpasswd: command not found
```

Comment: Hi David, thanks for looking at this. Please see the edit

Comment: Hi David, that did work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have `htpasswd` installed on your system to manage HTTP users. You can use the one from the [Apache HTTP Server utility programs](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/apache2-utils) [image: Install apache2-utils] package. Even though it's meant for Apache and not Squid, the password file format is the same (according to your reports).